# What is this pointer inside a class C++/ OOP concept called?

Tags: c++, oop

```
class Node { 
public: 
    int data; 
    Node* next; 
};
```

In this Node is a class, but I did not understand what `Node* next` is. Is it like a class constructor?

Comment: That is a singly linked list. It's just a pointer to the next node.

Comment: *Is it like a class constructor?* Just another member variable that just happens to point at an instance of a `Node`. If this has any fancy name (other than maybe singly linked list) I don't know it.

Comment: It just means each instance of `Node` contains a pointer to another instance of `Node`.     Set things up so the `Node`s are in a chain, with the last `Node` in the chain containing a null pointer, and you have produced a singly linked list.    Set up the pointers in other ways (e.g. by following the chain, eventually you come back to the original node) then you can create other data structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a class constructor, it's just a second public member-variable.  It's of type `Node*` rather than of type `int`, but otherwise it's similar to the `int data;` line.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `next` is a public field inside the class Node, which is of type `Node*`

The class `Node` is a linked list with data of type `int`.

equivalent to:

```
struct Node {  
    int data; 
    Node* next; 
};
```

Comment: The size of each node itself is not 4 bytes, but the data (that is, int) is usually 4 bytes. You are right though, size of int can change per architecture.